# Biographical details of Rabbi Baruch Ben Haim z"l

Tags: rabbis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

I am a big fan of Rabbi Baruch Ben Haim's teachings, and would like to know more about who he is, where he was born, where he studied and who was his teachers?

Did he have a *mechudash* way of psak?

{On a side note, I also wanted to know why Hacham Baruch Ben Haim was considered to be a Syrian Rav if he was actually born in Iraq?}

Comment: I don't know if he's considered a Syrian Rav; but, he served as a spiritual leader of the Syrian Jewish community of Brooklyn from age 28 until his passing at age 83 (55 years). Clearly, he would not have been accepted as a spiritual leader were he not to have been incredibly sensitive to Syrian Jewish practice (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Ben_Haim).

Comment: "Did he have a mechudash way of psak?" seems on topic.

Comment: @DoubleAA I feel kinda hated on here, always get blocked from asking, always something wrong.

Comment: @Moshe I assure you no one hates you. If things are wrong with your posts that has nothing to do with you, I'm sure. Everyone has a learning curve. Consider taking our short [tour] to help familiarize yourself with some of the way things work around here.

Comment: @DoubleAA But this question now is clear why isn't it up?

Comment: @Moshe Because much of what it asks is off topic for this site. We don't accept any question about anything. Only questions about Judaism. See this post http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473/759 for more details about what topics are on-topic for this site.

Comment: This just came up in the review queue for reopening, and I tend to agree with Double’s comments from 2016. If this were edited to focus on his method of psak I’d vote to reopen, but as it currently stands it’s mostly off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He was considered a Syrian Rav because he served the community for many years.

He was also accepted by them as such, despite being from an Iraqi background, because he was considered a tremendous Torah scholar and was highly respected among his fellow Chachamim including Rav Ovadia Yosef (his chavrusa) and Rav Ben Zion Abba Shaul with whom he studied together in the illustrious Yeshivat Porat Yosef. The Syrian community was very smart to not let his non Syrian background to stand in the way of seeing his greatness.

Furthermore he was considered one of the foremost talmidim of [Rav Ezra Attias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezra_Attiya) who was himself was born in Aleppo, Syria and that carried a lot of weight and credibility within the Syrian community, therefore he was not considered an outsider.

Moreover, Rav Ben Chaim was married to the daughter of Rav Yaakov Kassin. Rav Yaakov was the chief rabbi of the Syrian community and that also gave him legitimacy within the community.

Comment: "Rav Yaakov was the chief rabbi of the Syrian community" I thought Rav Ben Haim was?

Comment: Before him. After he passed away Rav Ben Chaim took over.